# Filtrar data a traves de AJAX con POST request Laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, eloquent

Muy buenas noches amigos.

Tengo un inconveniente con el framework de laravel y no puedo conseguir realizar una tarea sencilla.

Cuando escribo en un input automaticamente envio via AJAX por POST el value del input para filtrar mi tabla de users.

```
$("#cedula").keyup(function(){

    var cedula = parseInt($(this).val());

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ URL::route('traerNombre') }}',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: {
                documento: cedula   
            },
        success: function(result){
        //var arrData = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(result);
        //$("#usuario").val(nombre);
        },
        error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);
        }});
    });
```

Como ven coloco el token y todo bien puesto que cuando testeo desde el controlador devuelvo lo que recibo correctamente.

Aqui esta mi metodo personalizado desde el modelo (documento es mi columna donde guardo el numero de identificacion de mis usuarios):

```
public function scopeCedula($query, $cedula)
{
    return $query->where('documento', 'LIKE' ,'%$cedula%');
}
```

Y aqu'i esta mi controller:

```
public function cedula(Request $request)
{
    $cedula = $request->documento;    
    $user   =  User::cedula($cedula);

    return response()->json($user);
}
```

Me devuelve un error 500.

Pero si lo hago de esta manera:

```
    public function cedula(Request $request)
{
    $cedula = $request->documento;    
    $user   =  User::all();

    return response()->json($user);
}
```

si me devuelve la coleccion completa de los usuarios de la tabla.

Por favor necesito su ayuda gracias.

Comment: nos explicas por favor la declaración y funcionalidad del método estático cédula que usas en el bloque donde te sale ese error, por que veo que usas el modelo User::cedula pero como declaraste la funcionalidad de dicho método estático

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Según Laravel me lo permite, cuando llamo a User::cedula($cedula), es como si escribiera User::where('documento', 'LIKE', '%$cedula%')